# AWS Lambda function to post an email JSON to server submitting incorrect Data

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-ses

I am using using AWS SES to post an email from an s3 bucket to a method on my server. I have an SES rule set that writes said email to the bucket (which works), then there is a lambda function which posts to a function on my server. 
Here is the lambda function I am using (minus a few pieces of information).

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var https = require('https');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var queryString = require('querystring');

var bucketName = '<My-Bucket-Name>';
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    var sendToServer = function(emaildata) {
        // Options and headers for the HTTP request  
        var dataString = queryString.stringify(emaildata);

        var options = {
            host: '<My-Host-Name>',
            port: 443,
            path: '<My-PATH>',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(dataString),
                     }
        };

        // Setup the HTTP request
        process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
        var req = https.request(options, function (res) {

            res.setEncoding('utf-8');

            // Collect response data as it comes back.
            var responseString = '';
            res.on('data', function (data) {
                responseString += data;
            });

            // Log the responce received from Twilio.
            // Or could use JSON.parse(responseString) here to get at individual properties.
            res.on('end', function () {
                console.log('Response: ' + responseString);
                context.succeed();
            });
        });

        // Handler for HTTP request errors.
        req.on('error', function (e) {
            console.error('HTTP error: ' + e.message);
            context.fail();
        });

        // Send the HTTP request to the Twilio API.
        // Log the message we are sending to Twilio.
        console.log('Start API call');
        req.write(dataString);
        req.end();
    }

    var sesNotification = event.Records[0].ses;
    // Retrieve the email from your bucket
    console.log("sesNotification = " + event.Records);
    console.log("Key value = " + sesNotification.mail.messageId);
    s3.getObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: sesNotification.mail.messageId
    }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
            context.fail();
        } else {
            console.log("Raw email:\n" + data.Body);
            sendToServer(data);
        }
    });
};
```

The php script I am posting to has the the following code:

```
$this->layout=false;
$obj = json_encode($this->request->data);
```

I then email $obj to my personal email.

The message I get is:

```
{"AcceptRanges":"bytes","LastModified":"Wed, 02 Dec 2015 19:55:09 GMT","ContentLength":"2797","ETag":"\"1ee74034ec791514fa57d1ff13452737\"","ContentType":"application\/octet-stream","Metadata":"","Body":""}
```

What I am looking for is all the information pertaining to the email so I can do some fancy stuff on my server. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in your S3 callback function. data.Body isn't actually simple object that can be serialized. You have to stream it to a buffer, file, or turn it into a string (which I think is being done in your log statement).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property

Before your sendToServer call, try:

`data.StringBody = data.Body.toString()`